# Why do martingales have same expectation?

Tags: expectation, martingales

Let $X_i, i \geq 1$ be a $(\mathcal{F}_i)_{i \geq 1}$ measurable sequence of Random variables.

It is a martingale if

$$E[X_{i+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_i] = X_i.$$

But how do we conclude from this that $E[X_i]=E[X_j]$ for all $i,j$?

**MY IDEA:**

show it by induction on $i$. Let $\mu:=E[X_1]$.

Then $$E[X_2] = E[E[X_2 \mid \mathcal{F}_1]]=E[X_1]=\mu,$$

and $$E[X_i]=E[E[X_i \mid \mathcal{F}_{i-1}]]= E[X_{i-1}]=\mu$$

by induction, using the property that the conditional expectation and the random variable itself have the same expectation.

Is this correct?

In the same way one can show that for a submartingale one has $E[X_i] \geq E[X_j]$ for $i \geq j$ and for a supermartingale $E[X_i] \leq E[X_j]$ for $i \geq j$. Is this correct?

Comment: "It is a martingale if $E[X_{i+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_i] = E[X_i].$" This is incorrect. It should be $E[X_{i+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_i] = X_i$. Note that $E[X_{i+1} \mid \mathcal{F}_i]$ is a random variable, but $E[X_i]$ is a constant.

Comment: Of course, this was just a typo. In my proof I have used it correctly, though. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that an equivalent definition is $E[X_n \mid \mathcal F_m] = X_m$ if $n > m$.

The fact that they are equivalent can be proven in a very similar way as you did. In any case it's a little more *intuitive* now, as you can just take the expectation to both sides to conclude that $E[X_n] = E[X_m]$ for $n > m$ which is what we wanted

Comment: How is this different from his approach? The only difference I see is the indices, $i$ and $i+1$ versus $n$ and $m$. For the rest isn't it the same?

Comment: I think the difference is that we do not need induction in that case. So the "induction" is already in the definition of the martingale.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense indeed. Thanks, missed that one.

Comment: I have one more question concerning this: Is there an easy way to conclude that, in case that $X_n$ converges (let's say P-a.s.) to $X$, that then $E[X]=E[X_0]$? Or does this result not extend to infinity?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are indeed correct. :)